# liquibase:diff command throws Null pointer exception

Tags: liquibase, liquibase-hibernate

I generated liquibase schema with `mvn liquibase:generateChangeLog`, and when I try to execute the diff command with `mvn liquibase:diff` I get an error message  **Error getting default schema java.lang.NullPointerException**. Not sure what's wrong with my configuration. I am testing Liquibase 3.6 with Spring Boot and Spring JPA

## Error Message

```
 mvn liquibase:diff
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] -------------------------< com:liquibasetest >--------------------------
[INFO] Building liquibasetest 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- liquibase-maven-plugin:3.6.3:diff (default-cli) @ liquibasetest ---
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Parsing Liquibase Properties File
[INFO]   File: src/main/resources/liquibase.properties
[INFO]   'outputChangeLogFile' in properties file is not being used by this task.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Starting Liquibase at Tue, 12 Feb 2019 00:05:05 EST (version 3.6.3 built at 2019-01-29 11:34:48)
[WARNING] Can not use class liquibase.ext.hibernate.database.HibernateSpringDatabase as a Liquibase service because org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionRegistry is not in the classpath
[INFO] Executing on Database: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/flywaytest?currentSchema=flywaytest
[WARNING] Unknown database: Hibernate
[INFO] Performing Diff on database root@localhost @ jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/flywaytest?currentSchema=flywaytest (Default Schema: flywaytest)
[INFO] Error getting default schema
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor$QueryCallableStatementCallback.doInCallableStatement (JdbcExecutor.java:452)
    at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor.execute (JdbcExecutor.java:93)
    at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor.query (JdbcExecutor.java:135)
    at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor.query (JdbcExecutor.java:146)
    at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor.queryForObject (JdbcExecutor.java:154)
    at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor.queryForObject (JdbcExecutor.java:169)
    at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor.queryForObject (JdbcExecutor.java:164)
    at liquibase.database.AbstractJdbcDatabase.getConnectionSchemaName (AbstractJdbcDatabase.java:327)
    at liquibase.database.AbstractJdbcDatabase.getDefaultSchemaName (AbstractJdbcDatabase.java:292)
    at liquibase.CatalogAndSchema.customize (CatalogAndSchema.java:151)
    at liquibase.snapshot.SnapshotGeneratorFactory.createSnapshot (SnapshotGeneratorFactory.java:184)
    at liquibase.command.core.DiffCommand.createReferenceSnapshot (DiffCommand.java:221)
    at liquibase.command.core.DiffCommand.createDiffResult (DiffCommand.java:143)
    at liquibase.command.core.DiffToChangeLogCommand.run (DiffToChangeLogCommand.java:51)
    at liquibase.command.AbstractCommand.execute (AbstractCommand.java:19)
    at liquibase.integration.commandline.CommandLineUtils.doDiffToChangeLog (CommandLineUtils.java:237)
    at liquibase.integration.commandline.CommandLineUtils.doDiffToChangeLog (CommandLineUtils.java:212)
    at org.liquibase.maven.plugins.LiquibaseDatabaseDiff.performLiquibaseTask (LiquibaseDatabaseDiff.java:177)
    at org.liquibase.maven.plugins.AbstractLiquibaseMojo.execute (AbstractLiquibaseMojo.java:366)
    at org.liquibase.maven.plugins.LiquibaseDatabaseDiff.execute (LiquibaseDatabaseDiff.java:136)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  3.773 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-02-12T00:05:07-05:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.liquibase:liquibase-maven-plugin:3.6.3:diff (default-cli) on project liquibasetest: Error setting up or running Liquibase: liquibase.command.CommandExecutionException: java.lang.NullPointerException -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

## liquibase.properties

```
outputChangeLogFile= src/main/resources/db/db.changelog-master.xml
driver=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/flywaytest?currentSchema=flywaytest
username=root
password=bcmc1234
```

## db.changlog-master.xml

```
<?xml version="1.1" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<databaseChangeLog xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog" xmlns:ext="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-ext.xsd http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.6.xsd">
    <changeSet author="pjadda (generated)" id="1549947881457-1">
        <createTable tableName="country">
            <column name="id" type="BIGINT">
                <constraints primaryKey="true"/>
            </column>
            <column name="name" type="VARCHAR(45)"/>
            <column name="code" type="VARCHAR(45)"/>
            <column name="iso_code" type="VARCHAR(45)"/>
            <column name="region_id" type="BIGINT"/>
        </createTable>
    </changeSet>
    <changeSet author="pjadda (generated)" id="1549947881457-2">
        <createTable tableName="region">
            <column name="id" type="BIGINT">
                <constraints primaryKey="true"/>
            </column>
            <column name="name" type="VARCHAR(45)"/>
        </createTable>
    </changeSet>
    <changeSet author="pjadda (generated)" id="1549947881457-3">
        <createIndex indexName="region_fk_idx" tableName="country">
            <column name="region_id"/>
        </createIndex>
    </changeSet>
    <changeSet author="pjadda (generated)" id="1549947881457-4">
        <addForeignKeyConstraint baseColumnNames="region_id" baseTableName="country" constraintName="region_fk" deferrable="false" initiallyDeferred="false" onDelete="NO ACTION" onUpdate="NO ACTION" referencedColumnNames="id" referencedTableName="region" validate="true"/>
    </changeSet>
</databaseChangeLog>
```

## pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com</groupId>
    <artifactId>liquibasetest</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>liquibasetest</name>
    <description>Liquibase Test project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-boot.version>2.1.1.RELEASE</spring-boot.version>
        <spring-boot-admin.version>2.1.1</spring-boot-admin.version>
        <hibernate.version>5.4.0.Final</hibernate.version>
        <liquibase-maven-plugin.version>3.6.3</liquibase-maven-plugin.version>
        <liquibase-hibernate5.version>3.6</liquibase-hibernate5.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-envers</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
            <artifactId>liquibase-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
            <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${liquibase-maven-plugin.version}</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>de.codecentric</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-admin-starter-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>de.codecentric</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-admin-starter-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
<!--        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>de.codecentric</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-admin-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-boot-admin.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
                <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${liquibase-maven-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <propertyFile>src/main/resources/liquibase.properties</propertyFile>
                    <changeLogFile>src/main/resources/db/db.changelog-master.xml</changeLogFile>
                    <diffChangeLogFile>src/main/resources/db/changelog/${maven.build.timestamp}_changelog.xml</diffChangeLogFile>
                    <logging>info</logging>
                </configuration>
  <!--              <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>generate-db-prev</id>
                        <phase>process-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>update</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <dropFirst>true</dropFirst>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>generate-db-diff</id>
                        <phase>process-test-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>diff</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>-->
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.liquibase.ext</groupId>
                        <artifactId>liquibase-hibernate4</artifactId>
                        <version>3.6</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>

            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Might be a silly question, but just to check all the possibilities - does the schema `flywaytest` exist on both databases you are comparing?

Comment: Yes. Actually, it's the same database. I am trying to update existing database based on changes to my Spring JPA classes

Comment: I don't see where you have configured things so that diff compares the Spring JPA to the live database, but I haven't ever used Liquibase with Spring JPA.You might also turn the logging up from info to debug while doing this to get better information. I also noticed that there was a warning `[WARNING] Can not use class liquibase.ext.hibernate.database.HibernateSpringDatabase as a Liquibase service because org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionRegistry is not in the classpath` so that could be the issue.

Comment: I've got same problem using java11. Running with java8 works fine for me.

Comment: @SergioGonzalez I have not tested with Java 11. Maybe you can check liquibase docs for more information

Comment: @SergioGonzalez I tested Java 11, it works fine. Please let me know your issue

Comment: @Jadda probably it's some specific scenarios we have in our enviromemnt. Everything is described on https://liquibase.jira.com/browse/CORE-3429

Comment: @SergioGonzalez My code works with liquibase 3.5.5 and liquibase-hibernate5  3.6 version on Java 11 and 8, but not with latest dependencies. There is an active bug for this and waiting for the fix. So, please use the mentioned versions

Comment: Thanks @Jadda it looks like this is the issue, but unfortunately i've got a new problem
`javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"http://www.hibernate.org/xsd/orm/hbm", local:"hibernate-mapping"). Expected elements are <{}hibernate-mapping>`

It looks like related with next link https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-12893

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update**: As of 03-Jun-2019 latest liquibase version 3.6.3 and liquibase-hibernate5 plugin version 3.7 have a [bug](https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase-hibernate/issues/198)  and will update the post once it's resolved. Meanwhile, use **liquibase-maven-plugin version 3.5.5** and **liquibase-hibernate5 version 3.6**

**Solution**:

I figured out the issue. Spring JPA uses Hibernate 5.x and I configured `liquibase-hibernate4` in liquibase dependencies.  Thanks to Steve Donnie for pointing out the warning message. Changing liquibase version created another exception related Spring JPA, so I moved Spring JPA dependency to liquibase dependencies and added 
`validation-api` dependency to prevent validation errors

```
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.liquibase.ext</groupId>
                    <artifactId>liquibase-hibernate5</artifactId>
                    <version>${liquibase-hibernate5.version}</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
                    <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
                    <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
                    <version>${validation-api.version}</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
```

so updated pom.xml is as below

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com</groupId>
    <artifactId>liquibasetest</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>liquibasetest</name>
    <description>Liquibase Test project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-boot.version>2.1.2.RELEASE</spring-boot.version>
        <spring-boot-admin.version>2.1.1</spring-boot-admin.version>
        <hibernate.version>5.4.0.Final</hibernate.version>
        <liquibase-maven-plugin.version>3.5.5</liquibase-maven-plugin.version>
        <liquibase-hibernate5.version>3.6</liquibase-hibernate5.version>
        <validation-api.version>2.0.1.Final</validation-api.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-envers</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>de.codecentric</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-admin-starter-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>de.codecentric</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-admin-starter-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
            <artifactId>liquibase-core</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
            <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${liquibase-maven-plugin.version}</version>
        </dependency>



        <!--        <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
                    <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
                    <scope>runtime</scope>
                </dependency>-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>de.codecentric</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-admin-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-boot-admin.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
                <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${liquibase-maven-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <propertyFile>src/main/resources/liquibase.properties</propertyFile>
                    <changeLogFile>src/main/resources/db/db.changelog-master.xml</changeLogFile>
                    <diffChangeLogFile>src/main/resources/db/changelog/${maven.build.timestamp}_changelog.xml</diffChangeLogFile>
                    <logging>debug</logging>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.liquibase.ext</groupId>
                        <artifactId>liquibase-hibernate5</artifactId>
                        <version>${liquibase-hibernate5.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
                        <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
                        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
                        <version>${validation-api.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>

            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```